# How to read input from the user in a bash subshell

Tags: bash, shell

I have a snippet that users paste in their terminals. It looks like this:

```
"script..." | sudo bash -s ARG1
```

The script part is actually a curl command that gets a script over HTTP.
I also need an argument to be passed to that script, and I can do it with -s argument to bash. (This is all part of the snippet)

However, I also need "read" to work.. I want to prompt the user for additional configuration. It doesn't work now, probably due to Subshells / stdin being redirected.

How can I do it?

Comment: your expectation that it doesn't work is correct. Solutions involve Scrutinizer's answer as well as downloading to a tmp file and executing that, skipping the `-s` option, which slurps input from the script (which includes I/O, which is what's causing the failure of read)